# Return value of fgets into main function

Tags: c, codeblocks, fgets

Function `fWord` asks my input, and should return the first word it encounters (until the first space).
It works on Online Visual Studio, but if I try to compile it with codeBlocks, my input doesn't get printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * fWord();
char * test;

int main()
{
    test = fWord();
    printf("%s\n", test);

    return 0;
}

char * fWord() // ONLY READ THE FIRST WORD
{
    char buffer[20];
    char * input = buffer;

    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    input = strtok(input, " ");
    input[strcspn(input, "\r\n")] = 0; // REMOVES NEWLINE FROM GETLINE

    return input;
}
```

Comment: Also, `sizeof(input)` will be the size of a `char *`. Not the size of the buffer.

Comment: `input[strcspn(input, "\r\n")] = 0;` better done _before_ `strtok()`.

Answer (score 2):

The buffer

```
char buffer[20];
```

has local storage. It is allocated in the stack and it is released as soon as `fWord` returns.

You need to allocate it externally (either as global variable or as a local variable of function `main` passing it as a new parameter of `fWord`) or keep allocating within `fWord` but *dynamically* (using `malloc ()`).

Furthermore, as correctly noticed by @lurker in comments section, the call

```
fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
```

tells `fgets()` to read at most `sizeof(input)` characters. But it will actually be the size of a `char *` pointer, either 4 or 8 according to your architecture.

In conclusion, your program will become:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_INPUT_LEN 20

char * fWord(void);

int main(void)
{
    char *test = fWord();
    if (test) //fWord might return a NULL pointer 
    {
        printf("%s\n", test);
        free(test);
    }
    return 0;
}

char * fWord(void) // ONLY READ THE FIRST WORD
{
    char * input = malloc(MAX_INPUT_LEN);
    if (input)
    {
        fgets(input, MAX_INPUT_LEN, stdin);
        input[strcspn(input, "\r\n")] = 0; // REMOVES NEWLINE FROM GETLINE
        input = strtok(input, " ");
    }
    return input;
}
```

Comment: I’ve made buffer my global variable and changes the position of strtok(). What should my sizeof contain. Buffer?

Comment: @CuypersMichel oh, for my example I chose an inner malloc, instead.. Nevermind, for your problem defining the buffer globally is ok. Yes: if you pass to sizeof an array reference you get its size in bytes. Being it an array of chars it is what you need

Comment: I got it working, i had an issue with the NULL pointer. Just saw that fixed that in my code with an if. Thank you again.