# How to call the value of one function from another function in C?

Tags: c, function

How to call **new_acc** `name` and `address` into **view_list** function. I want to show the name and address to be printed in **view_list** function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 15

int new_acc();
int view_list();    
int main(){
    int one=1, two=2, three=3, four=4, five=5, six=6, seven=7, new_account, list; char choice[MAX];

    printf("%d. Create new account\n",one);
    printf("%d. View customers list\n",two);

    printf("Enter you choice: ");
    fgets(choice, MAX, stdin);
    if (choice[0]-'0'==one){new_account = new_acc();}
    else if(choice[0]-'0'==six){list = view_list();}
    else{printf("This is wrong");}
    return 0;}

int new_acc(){
    char name[15], address[30];  
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin);

    printf("Enter your Address: ");
    fgets(address, sizeof address, stdin);
    return 0;}

int view_list(){
    printf("Here is your name: %d",name);
    printf("Here is your name: %d",address);
    return 0;}
```

Comment: Learn more about [function pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer), [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), and [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)). Read more about [the C programming language](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Look for inspiration into existing C code on [github](https://github.com/)

Comment: I put name and address in main.

Comment: Also read or at least bookmark [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), practically the C11 standard. Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler (with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` ...)

Comment: Trying to access local variables outside the function they are defined seems to be a common mistake. I answered to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61622203/11336762) just two days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have just started learning C language.

It is a very basic concept of C language (or any programming language that supports functional paradigm) that each function has its own space.

At a very basic level, I will say that you need to think that each function is a separate block and one block can not peek inside another block, but they can only call them or provide them with some values but they can not share or look inside each other.

So, there are possibly two solutions either you provide the values to the other function by passing them as an argument or you just place those variables at some place where both the functions can share them (global variables).

```
/**
 * This is the functional approach.
 *
 * Since name and address were arrays so, we need pointers to supply them here.
 * and in the `printf()` I used "%s", it is used to print strings. "%d" prints
 * integers, numbers only 
 */
int view_list(char* name, char* address) {
    printf("Here is your name: %s", name);
    printf("Here is your name: %s", address);
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
/**
 * This is the procedural approach.
 */

char name[15], address[30];

int new_acc() {
    // Instead of declaring them here.
    // declare them in globally.
    //
    // char name[15], address[30];
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin);

    printf("Enter your Address: ");
    fgets(address, sizeof address, stdin);
    return 0;
}
int view_list() {
    printf("Here is your name: %s", name);
    printf("Here is your name: %s", address);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay but how to save the values of variables so that I could call them in **view_list**. Whenever I type my name and address, I am unable to call them in view_list.

Comment: The same way you are currently doing, but i will prefer using `gets(const* dest)` instead of `fgets()`. moreover sizeof should be used with paranthesis.

Comment: Are you using the Borland IDE (Turbo C++) ?